# Cancel observable based on payload rather than effect

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, ngrx

I have a service that makes http requests to a backend I don't control to get marketing page contents. Sometimes, I need to load more than one piece of marketing content at the same time. I can create an effect that calls the service.

```
@Effect()
marketingContent$ = this.actions$
  .ofType(LOAD_MARKETING_CONTENT)
  .switchMap(({ payload }) => this.marketingService.getContent(payload)
    .map(content => Action.LoadMarketingContentComplete(content))
  )
```

This works fine, and I can call `store.dispatch(Action.LoadMarketingContent('A'))`.

The problem is that if I need to load more than one piece of marketing content at a time the `.switchMap` will cancel the previous request.

```
store.dispatch(Action.LoadMarketingContent('A'));
store.dispatch(Action.LoadMarketingContent('B'));
// Only `'B'` is loaded since 'A' gets canceled before it completes
```

I can use `.mergeMap` instead of `.switchMap`, but then duplicate requests won't get canceled.

I can also use separate actions to load each piece of marketing content, but that would require creating an action and effects for each piece.

Is there a way that I can use `.switchMap` to cancel only requests for the same content (where `payload` is the same?) or another way to make simultaneous different requests while canceling duplicate requests in the same stream?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you introduce a `CANCEL_MARKETING_CONTENT` action you could do something like this with `mergeMap`:

```ts
@Effect()
marketingContent$ = this.actions$
  .ofType(LOAD_MARKETING_CONTENT)
  .mergeMap(({ payload }) => this.marketingService
    .getContent(payload)
    .map(content => Action.LoadMarketingContentComplete(content))
    .takeUntil(this.actions$.ofType(CANCEL_MARKETING_CONTENT))
  );
```

Basically, that would let you load as many pieces of marketing content as you like, but it would be up to you to cancel any pending loads by dispatching an `CANCEL_MARKETING_CONTENT` action before you dispatch the `LOAD_MARKETING_CONTENT` action(s).

For example, to load only piece `A`, you'd do this:

```ts
store.dispatch(Action.CancelMarketingContent());
store.dispatch(Action.LoadMarketingContent('A'));
```

And to load both pieces `A` and `B`, you'd do this:

```ts
store.dispatch(Action.CancelMarketingContent());
store.dispatch(Action.LoadMarketingContent('A'));
store.dispatch(Action.LoadMarketingContent('B'));
```

---

Actually, there is a similar - but neater - way of doing it and it doesn't involve using another action.

You can use the dispatch of the same action with the same payload as the cancellation trigger. For example:

```ts
@Effect()
marketingContent$ = this.actions$
  .ofType(LOAD_MARKETING_CONTENT)
  .mergeMap(({ payload }) => this.marketingService
    .getContent(payload)
    .map(content => Action.LoadMarketingContentComplete(content))
    .takeUntil(this.actions$
      .ofType(LOAD_MARKETING_CONTENT)
      .skip(1)
      .filter(({ payload: next }) => next === payload)
    )
  );
```

From memory, `skip` will be needed to skip the action currently being handled by the effect. And the answer assumes that `payload` is `"A"` or `"B"`, etc.

Comment: Great answer. From my tests, I believe the skip(1) is not needed.

Comment: Its giving me error
Property 'ofType' does not exist on type 'Actions<Action>' Can you please help me with this error do i need to use the pipe operator here ?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than cancel the effect specifically, you can change the effect to retrieve marketing content in groups and still take advantage of `switchMap` for canceling subsequent requests.

```
@Effect()
marketingContent$ = this.actions$
  .ofType(LOAD_MARKETING_CONTENT)
  .switchMap(({ payload }) => forkJoin(
    payload.map(name => this.marketingService.getContent(payload))
  ).map(content => Action.LoadMarketingContentComplete(content))
```

In this case, the `payload` would be an array of content names to retrieve instead of an individual name which allows you to load content as groups.